# Can't create targets within external sass Grunt task (with Grunt-Sass)

Tags: sass, gruntjs

I want to create targets like this:

grunt/sass.js:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    alpha: {
        options: {
            includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
        },
        dist: {
            options: {
                outputStyle: 'compressed'
            },
            files: {
                'css/app.css': 'scss/app2.scss'
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Gruntfile.js:

```js
module.exports = function (grunt) {
require('load-grunt-config')(grunt);
};
```

I can't get this working properly. Only when I recode the sass.js file into the following Grunt compiles it into CSS:

```js
module.exports = {
  options: {
    includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
  },
  dist: {
    options: {
    outputStyle: 'compressed'
    },
  files: {
    'css/app.css': 'scss/app.scss'
    }
  }
};
```

How can I create those targets so I can execute commands like 'grunt sass:alpha', so I can create several templates.

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve it by changing grunt/sass.js to this:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
    options: {
        includePaths: ['bower_components/foundation/scss']
    },
    alpha: {
        options: {
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        },
        files: {
            'css/alpha.css': 'scss/app_alpha.scss'
        }
    },
    beta: {
        options: {
            outputStyle: 'compressed'
        },
        files: {
            'css/beta.css': 'scss/app_beta.scss'
        }
    }
};
```